# decrypt pfx OR p12 using iaik_jce.jar in Java throws Unable to decrypt PrivateKey! exception

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, jce, iaik-jce

I obtained iaik_jce.jar file from thirdparty. I am using it to decrypt a pfx file. When i am calling decrypt api then i am getting Unable to decrypt PrivateKey! exception. Below is the piece of code which i use for decryption.

```
    FileInputStream inStream = new FileInputStream(currentCredentialFile.getAbsoluteFile());
pkcs12 = new PKCS12(inStream);
pkcs12.decrypt(currentCredentialPassword.toCharArray());
```

Below is the exception stack trace

```
Caused by: iaik.pkcs.PKCSException: Unable to decrypt PrivateKey!
    at iaik.pkcs.pkcs12.AuthenticatedSafe.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at iaik.pkcs.pkcs12.PKCS12.decrypt(Unknown Source)
    at com.raja.testapp.TestApplicatioin.main(TestApplicatioin.java:32)
```

Do i need to make any configuration changes for using iaik_jce.jar file for decryption.

Comment: PFX file is commonly used to bundle a private key with its X.509 certificate. Why would you want to decrypt that?  You only decrypt cipher text.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. I needed to do some initialization which i did not do before.

```
iaik.security.provider.IAIK.addAsProvider(false);
```

Adding the above statement did the trick